# Create udev rules file from two input file

Tags: linux, perl, awk

I am looking for a solution to create Oracle ASM udev rules file for linux. I have two input file. file1 has info of ASM disk requirement and file2 has disk information.

For example, line 2 of file1 is showing DATA12 need 3 disk(DATA12_01,DATA12_02,DATA12_03) of each 128G. file2 has all disk info with size. From these two input file I need to create output file shown bellow.

**cat file1**

```
Count - size - name
3 - 128 GB DATA12
1 - 128 GB TEMP02
2 - 4 GB ARCH03
2 - 1 GB ARCH04
1 - 3 GB  ORAC01
```

**cat file2**

```
UUID                                        Size
360060e80166ef70000016ef700006700           128.00 GiB
360060e80166ef70000016ef700006701           128.00 GiB
360060e80166ef70000016ef700006702           128.00 GiB
360060e80166ef70000016ef700006703           128.00 GiB
360060e80166ef70000016ef700006730             4.00 GiB
360060e80166ef70000016ef700006731             4.00 GiB
360060e80166ef70000016ef700006733             1.00 GiB
360060e80166ef70000016ef700006734             1.00 GiB
360060e80166ef70000016ef700006735             3.00 GiB
```

**Output File**

```
ACTION=="add|change", ENV{DM_NAME}=="360060e80166ef70000016ef700006700", SYMLINK+="udevlinks/DATA12_01"

ACTION=="add|change", ENV{DM_NAME}=="360060e80166ef70000016ef700006701", SYMLINK+="udevlinks/DATA12_02"

ACTION=="add|change", ENV{DM_NAME}=="360060e80166ef70000016ef700006702", SYMLINK+="udevlinks/DATA12_03"

ACTION=="add|change", ENV{DM_NAME}=="360060e80166ef70000016ef700006703", SYMLINK+="udevlinks/TEMP02_01"

ACTION=="add|change", ENV{DM_NAME}=="360060e80166ef70000016ef700006730", SYMLINK+="udevlinks/ARCH03_01"

ACTION=="add|change", ENV{DM_NAME}=="360060e80166ef70000016ef700006731", SYMLINK+="udevlinks/ARCH03_02"

ACTION=="add|change", ENV{DM_NAME}=="360060e80166ef70000016ef700006733", SYMLINK+="udevlinks/ARCH04_01"

ACTION=="add|change", ENV{DM_NAME}=="360060e80166ef70000016ef700006734", SYMLINK+="udevlinks/ARCH04_02"

ACTION=="add|change", ENV{DM_NAME}=="360060e80166ef70000016ef700006735", SYMLINK+="udevlinks/ORAC01_01"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one in AWK:

```
$ cat > test.awk
BEGIN {FS="([.]| +)"}   # field separator do deal with "." in file2 128.00
FNR==1 {next}           # skip header
NR==FNR {               # read available disks to pool from file1
    for(i=1; i<=$1; i++) 
        a[$5"_"0i]=$3   # name and set the disks into pool
    next} 
{
    for(i in a) {       # look for right sized disk
        if(a[i]==$2) {  # when found, print...
            printf "%s%s%s%s%s", "ACTION==\"add|change\", ENV{DM_NAME}==\"",$1,"\",\"SYMLINK+=\"udevlinks/",i,"\"\n"
            delete a[i] # ... and remove from pool
            break
        }
    } # if no device was found:
    old=len; len=length(a); if(old==len) {print "No device found for ",$0}
}
$ awk -f test.awk file1 file2
ACTION=="add|change", ENV{DM_NAME}=="360060e80166ef70000016ef700006700","SYMLINK+="udevlinks/DATA12_01"
ACTION=="add|change", ENV{DM_NAME}=="360060e80166ef70000016ef700006701","SYMLINK+="udevlinks/DATA12_02"
...
No device found for  THIS_IS_AN_EXAMPLE_OF_MISSING_DISK           666.00 GiB
```

Due to disk search using `for(i in a)` no order in which disks are read from the pool is guaranteed.

Comment: Awsome. greate solution. Also i am trying add another line "#uuid date" before each output. i tried bellow and its not working. its not giving any
error also.  <br/>

d="`date +%D`"  
printf "%s%s\n", "#\"",$1,"\" d"  <br/>
printf "%s%s%s%s%s", "ACTION==\"add|change\", ENV{DM_NAME}==\"",$1,"\",\"SYMLINK+=\"udevlinks/",i,"\"\n"  

output   <br/>
# 360060e801605a400000105a4000039ba  <br/>
ACTION=="add|change", ENV{DM_NAME}=="360060e801605a400000105a4000039ba","SYMLINK+="udevlinks/DATA07_01

Comment: Having issue with html line break.

Comment: Please give an example of desired output.

Comment: Out put I am looking for

Comment: # 360060e801605a400000105a4000039ba 08/24/16

Comment: ACTION=="add|change", ENV{DM_NAME}=="360060e801605a400000105a4000039ba","SYMLINK+="udevlinks/DATA07_01

Comment: Also, disk name is allways started with 01, example DATA07_01. if i need to start it in middle of disk number how that 
can be done. for example file1 has " 3 - 128 GB DATA07_12" then output of disk name should be started with DATA07_13